# Are references only for Documents in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Okay, so there is this "Reference" thing that I don't get about Firebase:

```
const docRef = firestore.collection('users').doc();
```

You can get a "reference" of a Document but you can't get a reference of a Collection?

Why?

Clearly there can be multiple docs in a collection but there can also be multiple collections in a doc, right? So how is that different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebase SDKs you will find [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference)s and [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference)s.

> A `DocumentReference` refers to a document location in a Firestore
> database and can be used to write, read, or listen to the location.
> The document at the referenced location may or may not exist.

> A `CollectionReference` object can be used for adding documents,
> getting document references, and querying for documents.

Note that a `CollectionReference` can refer to root collections as well as to sub-collections under a Document.